# How do I change the keystroke problem for OpenSeadragon?

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm trying to change the keys of OpenSeadragon, the default is left button and long press to drag the picture, I want to change it to right button long press and drag, what should I do, below is the code I tried, but it doesn't seem to work effect

```
<script>
        var mouse = OpenSeadragon.Button({
            element:'view',
        });
        mouse.isTracking(true)
        mouse.dragHandler(function (event){
            event.buttons = 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple "switch drag to the right mouse button" feature in OSD, but it's possible you could implement it. You'll have to disable the `viewer.innerTracker.dragHandler` by setting it to null, and then create new functions for these three handlers:

- viewer.innerTracker.nonPrimaryPressHandler
- viewer.innerTracker.moveHandler
- viewer.innerTracker.nonPrimaryReleaseHandler

You'll need to implement your own drag functionality, since OSD doesn't have a "non-primary drag" handler. As for the actual panning functionality, you can take a look at how it currently does it with the left mouse drag.

https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/d3ef7674874ce5b5fd5d52816acbe4708e24c44a/src/viewer.js#L2949